# Formatting date time formatting javascript function in .vue to server side entity framework query

Tags: javascript, html, entity-framework, datetime, vue.js

I want to remove the DateTime formatting from the client side vue table (slow to render with >500 rows) to the server side, but I'm not sure how!

I have a vue table with two columns start date and end date that get passed to formatDate()

```
<td>{{ formatDate(props.item.startDate) }}</td>
<td>{{ formatDate(props.item.endDate) }}</td>
```

in the view model they are nullable DateTimes

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

The formatDate method looks like this in the .vue file, where dayjs() is a component like moment.

```
formatDate(date) {
   if (!date) {
       return null
   }

   return dayjs(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
}
```

In the Entity Framework query I just fetch the dates like this

```
var recordsVM = records.Select(r => new GetRecordsReturnViewModel
{
     StartDate = r.StartDate,
     EndDate = r.EndDate,
     // fetch more data
}).Distinct();
```

I want to be able to perform the same operation in the linq statement but I'm not sure how!

I want something like this I think but the conversion won't work

```
var recordsVM = records.Select(r => new GetRecordsReturnViewModel
{
     StartDate = (r.StartDate != null) ? ((DateTime)r.StartDate).ToString("MM/DD/YYYY") as DateTime? : null,
     EndDate = (r.EndDate != null) ? ((DateTime)r.EndDate).ToString("MM/DD/YYYY") as DateTime? : null,

}).Distinct();
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the raw `DateTime` value?

Answer (score 0):

When formatting `DateTime.ToString()` you have to follow a specific format..

[This article outlines the formatting characters..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Below shows how to convert `DateTime` to string format from `ticks` as well as a `DateTime` object itself..

[Run this example online via DotNetFiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qaXrow)

```
using System;

namespace Root
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            /** could also do:
            var nowInTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks; */
            var nowInTicks = 636905426867055839;
            var nowString = new DateTime(nowInTicks).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Console.WriteLine(nowString);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sstt"));
        }
    }
}
/* RETURN: */
// 04/11/2019
// 04/11/2019 01:32:28AM // in UTC
```